# Что возвращает getComputedStyle().transform?

Tags: javascript, css3, transform

Делаю анимацию свойства `transform`. Нужно получить это свойство от элемента, для этого использую `getComputedStyle` и получаю `transform: "matrix(0.00234711662304943, 0.999997245517985, -0.999997245517985, 0.00234711662304943, 0.70308283859708, 299.550902185077)"` Что это ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это матрица 2D-трансформации. Очевидно же. 
[Поиграйся с ёжиком.](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/matritsa-preobrazovanii)

Comment: Возможно, но я не знаю что такое матрица 2D-трансформации (

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин, ссылку-то открой.

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо большое)

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин, кстати, есть и другие функции трансформации: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Это я знаю, но тоже спасибо))